# a javascript string problem?

Tags: javascript

i have this script, but i the `result.bgimage` is not showing up, i think `JS` thinks its a string rather than variable!!! how can i solve this problem? thanks

```
$('#bg')
    .animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
        $(this)
            .css({'background-image': 'url(result.bgimage)'})
            .animate({opacity: 1});
    });
```

Comment: What is `result.bgimage` supposed to be? If it's a variable, just put it outside the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#bg')
    .animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
        $(this)
            .css({'background-image': 'url(' + result.bgimage + ')'})
            .animate({opacity: 1});
    });
```